# Crystal Report connect via odbc postgres driver login failed when deploy to iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, crystal-reports, odbc

i working with asp.net & i want to render data by crystal report and my database is postgres and i use odbc to connect database with crystal report. In my local machine it's working fine

When i deploy my project to IIS it return error **Database logon failed.**

In another project is use database sql and not get error like this.

I have check odbc in local machine and server already (same setup)

Have some one working with postgres db and render by crystal ? Please help, thank you so much

Comment: check that the postgres db accepts connection from the IP of the server running IIS, then check the firewalls.

Comment: i fixed by set connection odbc 32 bit, not 64 bit